# In Eclipse System.out.print does not print anything on console (Running Eclipse as super user does)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

When I run a simple Hello-World application using eclipse does not print anything on the console. I have installed Eclipse Indigo using apt-get on Ubuntu.
Here is the trivial program I am trying to run:

```
public class testJava {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("Hello Java!!!");
    }

}
```

When I run it as Java application it just shows me termination messages on console

Strangely if I run Eclipse in Super user mode (sudo Eclipse) I can see the Hello Java message printed on console. Can anyone explain me the reason for this anomaly

Comment: is console disapparing very quickly?

Comment: Please provide the termination message that you see on the console.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: I won't say quickly...its just there as a tab.

Comment: It might be worth trying to isolate the problem a bit more. What happens if you try to execute that class as a normal user from the command line ? If you can see the messages then there is something wrong with Eclipse otherwise it's the JDK on your system (and related permissions that we need to sort out first)